# An order reduction problem.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider a differential equation of the form:

$F(t,x,\frac{dx}{dt},...,\frac{d^{n}x}{dt^{n}})=0$

and exist $\alpha$ and $m$ fixed such that:

$F(\lambda t, \lambda^{m}x,\lambda^{m-1}\frac{dx}{dt},...,\lambda^{m-n}\frac{d^{n}x}{dt^{n}})=\lambda^{\alpha}F(t,x,\frac{dx}{dt},...\frac{d^{n}x}{dt^{n}})$

The variable change and function $t=e^s$ and $x=e^{ms}w$, with $w=w(s)$ (so we have $x=x(t(s))$ and $x=x(w(s))$) transforms the first equation in another equation of the form:

$G(w,\frac{dw}{ds},...,\frac{d^{n}w}{ds^{n}})=0$

For a function G. In this new equation we can make the next variable change $z(w)=\frac{dw}{ds}(s(w))$, because doesn't appear the new variable s, so we get a one unit reduction for the order.

a) Prove that if we have the previous variable change and function proposed, we have

$\frac{d^{k}x}{dt^{k}}=e^{(m-k)s}h_{k}(w,\frac{dw}{ds},...,\frac{d^{k}w}{ds^{k}})$, for $k=0,...,n$

for functions $h_{k}(y_{1},...,y_{k+1})$ given, for $k=1,...,n$, by the recurrence:

$h_{k}(y_{1},...,y_{k+1})=(m-k+1)h_{k-1}(y_1,...,y_{k})+ \sum_{j=1}^{k} y_{j+1}\frac{\delta_{k-1}(y_{1},...,y_{k})}{\delta (y_{j})}\hspace{1cm}$With $h_{0}(y_{1})=y_{1}$

b) Prove that if we do the previous variable change and function change, the equation

$F(t,x,\frac{dx}{dt},...,\frac{d^{n}x}{dt^{n}})=0$

becomes into

$G(w,\frac{dw}{ds},...,\frac{d^{n}w}{ds^{n}})=0$

for a certain function G.

c) Apply the previous procedure for determining the general solution for the equation:

$4t^{2}x^{3}\frac{d^{2}x}{dt^{2}}=t^{2}-x^{4}$

This is my actual progress:

We have that

$\frac{dx}{dt} \frac{dt}{ds} = \frac{dx}{ds} + \frac{dx}{dw} \frac{dw}{ds}$

If we solve for $\frac{dx}{dt}$ and we substitute $\frac{dt}{ds}=e^{s}$, $\frac{dx}{ds}=me^{ms} w$, $\frac{dx}{dw}=e^{ms}$

We have:

$\frac{dx}{dt} = me^{(m-1)s}w + e^{(m-1)s}\frac{dw}{ds} \Rightarrow \frac{dx}{dt}=em^{(m-1)s}(mw+\frac{dw}{ds}) = e^{(m-1)s}h_{1}(w,\frac{dw}{ds})\hspace{1cm}$ with $h_{1}(w,\frac{dw}{ds})=mw+\frac{dw}{ds}$

If we consider now:

$h_{1}(w,\frac{dw}{ds})=h_{1}(y_{1},y_{2})=mw+\frac{dw}{ds}=mh_{0}(y_{1})+\sum_{j=1}^{1}y_{j+1}\frac{\delta h_{0}(w)}{\delta w}$

Now we should apply induction, if we suppose

$\frac{d^{k}x}{dt^{k}}=e^{(m-k)s}h_{k}(w,\frac{dw}{ds},...,\frac{d^{k}w}{ds^{k}})$

So, if we derive that expression, we have:

$\frac{d^{k+1}}{dt^{k+1}}=\frac{d}{dt}(e^{(m-k)s}h_{k}(w,\frac{dw}{ds},...,\frac{d^{k}w}{ds^{k}}))$

If we consider that t=t(s):

$\frac{d}{dt}(e^{(m-k)s}h_{k}(w,\frac{dw}{ds},...,\frac{d^{k}w}{ds^{k}})) = \frac{d}{ds}(e^{(m-k)s}h_{k}(w,\frac{dw}{ds},...,\frac{d^{k}w}{ds^{k}}))\frac{ds}{dt} $

So we have:

$\frac{d^{k+1}}{dt^{k+1}}=\frac{d}{ds}(e^{(m-k)s}h_{k}(w,\frac{dw}{ds},...,\frac{d^{k}w}{ds^{k}}))\frac{1}{e^{s}}$

I don't know how to continue.